# How to handle the OAuth 2.0 server response for Custom URI scheme? (Unity - Firebase authentication)

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am building a Unity app for iOS and Android. I am using Google Firebase for authentication (to get the users name and email address). Anyhow I followed and implemented the following tutorial:

https://medium.com/swlh/firebase-authentication-in-unity-with-google-other-providers-using-rest-apis-5997c8fff7c3

and it works well.

However in the tutorial, they use the Copy/ paste authorization URL (user has copy paste a code into the app). I would like to do this with the Custom URI scheme. I have already replaced the redirect_uri parameter and it works in my app (I am able to select my account and it bounces me back to the app).

This link: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app

however doesn’t explain how to handle the OAuth 2.0 server response for Custom URI scheme (step 4). Specifically I need help with exchanging the authentication code with IdToken. I am new to Firebase. Thank you!